# Least Common Multiple with while loop, Javascript

Tags: while-loop

I'm trying to find the least common multiple of an array of integers, e.g. if there are 2 numbers given (7, 3) then my task is to find the LCM of the numbers 3 through 7 (3,4,5,6,7 in that case).

My solution would be to add the maximum number to a new variable (var common) until the remainders of all of the numbers in the array (common % numBetween[i]) equal 0. There are more efficient ways of doing this, for example applying the Euclidean Algorithm, but I wanted to solve this my way.

The code:

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {

var numBetween = [];
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, arr);

while (max - min !== -1) {
  numBetween.push(min);
  min += 1;
} //this loop creates the array of integers, 1 through 13 in this case

var common = max;
var modulus = [1]; //I start with 1, so that the first loop could begin
var modSum = modulus.reduce(function (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0);

while (modSum !== 0) {
  modulus = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numBetween.length; i++) {
    modulus.push(common % numBetween[i]);
  }
  if (modSum !== 0) {
    common += max;
    break; //without this, the loop is infinite
  }    
}
return common;
}

smallestCommons([1,13]);
```

Now, the loop is either infinite (without break in the if statement) so I guess the modSum never equals 0, because the modulus variable always contains integers other than 0. I wanted to solve this by "resetting" the modulus to an empty array right after the loop starts, with

```
modulus = [];
```

and if I include the break, the loop stops after 1 iteration (common = 26). I can't quite grasp why my code isn't working. All comments are appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I may be false, but do you actually never change `modSum` within the while-loop? If so, this is your problem. You wanted to do this by using the function [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), but this does **not bind the given function**, so you have to call the function each time again in the loop.

Comment: I thought the modSum would change automatically every time the modulus changes. Could you show me how you mean? I'm a newbie and I'm not quite sure :) tried putting the reduce function again in the loop, same result.

Comment: @ZsoltBányai did you use it like this: `modSum = modulus.reduce(function(){...}, 0);`?

Comment: yes I did. Set modSum to 1 outside the loop (maybe that overwrites it everytime? If so, I'm not sure how to solve this), then the reduce function inside, just how I wrote before, after the for loop and before the if statement.

Comment: new comment cos I can't edit anymore. So: even if I define modSum as the reduce sum of modulus outside the loop and then write what you wrote inside, same result.

Comment: I am sorry, but i don't have any more suggestions then trying to debug it via `console.log("debug message");`.